# how to avoid links to be downloaded using wget

Tags: download, wget

I am trying to download some page of the following site http://computerone.altervista.org, just for testing…

My goal is to download just the pages matching the following patterns "`*JavaScript*`" and "`*index*`".

Actually if I try the following options

```
wget \
-A "*Javascript*, *index*" \
--exclude-domains http://computerone.altervista.org/rss-articles/ \
-e robots=off \
--mirror -E -k -p -np -nc --convert-links  \
--wait=5 -c  \
http://computerone.altervista.org
```

it works expect the fact it tries to download `http://computerone.altervista.org/rss-articles/` too.

My questions are:

1. why it tries to download the `http://computerone.altervista.org/rss-articles/` page?
2. how should I avoid it? I tried `--exclude-domains http://computerone.altervista.org/rss-articles/` option, but it try to download it

P.S.:
Looking to the source page I get:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="rss-articles/" />
```

Answer (score 2):

`wget -p` downloads all page requisites:

> man wget:
>
> To finish off this topic, it's worth knowing that Wget's idea of an
>              external document link is any URL specified in an `<A>` tag, an
>              `<AREA>` tag, or a `<LINK>` tag other than `<LINK
>              REL="stylesheet">`.

to exclude `rss-articles` use `-X` or `--exclude-directories`

`wget -A "*Javascript*, *index*" -X "rss-articles" -e robots=off --mirror -E -k -p -np -nc -c  http://computerone.altervista.org`

Comment: How to exclude multiple directories?